# How to remove the split line between GridColumns in GridControl?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I want to know how to remove the vertical line between Grid columns in `GridControl`, what should i do?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `ShowVerticalLines` property of the `TableView` to `false`:

```
<dxg:GridControl ...>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView ShowVerticalLines="False" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```